# using sessions variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my master page, I'm loading a variable in the session like this:

```
public partial class TheMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewUserPreferences SessionUserPreferences = new ViewUserPreferences();
            SessionUserPreferences = UserPreferences.GetUserPreferencesFromDB(6);
        }

    }

}
```

Then, in the code behind of a file, I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
               var test = Session["SessionUserPreferences"];
         }
}
```

But when I debug, test is null. What's causing the problem?

Also, if I put a break point in the master page, it doesn't trigger when I run the aspx page; is this normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you are missing the assignment part for UserPreferences.GetUserPreferencesFromDB(6) to the Session object. (I read the comments for @Greg's answer and you mentioned that even after that it is not working.)

Second, **Master Page's Page_Load Event is triggered after the Current Page's Page_Load Event**, hence the value of Session["SessionUserPreferences"] is null in Current Page's Page Load event since it is not set yet.

Check this link for further information on Page Events:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

Comment: ok, great! I put that line of code in the Page_Init event of the master page and now I'm getting the test variable of the page behind loaded when it reaches the breakpoint. In the master page, I put the line inside a if (!Page.IsPostBack){} condition. Is this what I need for all the session data to be loaded only once per session. What about call backs? Do I also need to check to avoid a reload of session data on call backs? Any other condition I need to check to avoid unnecessary reloads of session data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `Session["SessionUserPreferences"] = something;` somewhere before you attempt to retrieve that.  Are you setting it somewhere else that you didn't show?

Comment: Wouldn't that be in his Page_Load method `SessionUserPreferences = UserPreferences.GetUserPreferencesFromDB(6);` ? ;but you are probably right, it doesn't look right.

Comment: ok, I changed the line in the master page (top section of my question) to Session["SessionUserPreferences"] = UserPreferences.GetUserPreferencesFromDB(6); but in the code behind when I debug, I still get the variable test to null.